# Customer JQuery Plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am learning JQuery. I have a need to create a custom control. This control is going to basically render some HTML. Sometimes, I want to just get the HTML. My hope is to use the following syntax:

```
// Put generated html inside of "myElement". "myElement" is a div element.
$("#myElement").myPlugin({ value: 10 });

// Retrieve the html that myPlugin would place of a div element.
// Basically, I want the javascript equivalent of a C# static function here.
// But I think the following approach is wrong:
var html = myPlugin().getHtml(10); 
alert(html);
```

In an attempt to accomplish this, I'm using the following:

```
(function ($) {
  $.fn.myPlugin = function (element, options) {
    var defaults = { theValue: 0 }

    var plugin = this;
    plugin.settings = {};

    var $element = $(element),
    element = element;

    plugin.init = function () {
      plugin.settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
      var html = createHtml(defaults.theValue);
      $(element).html(html);      
    }

    plugin.getHtml = function (v) {
      return createHtml(v);
    }

    var createHtml(v) {
      return "<span>" + v + "</span>";
    }
})(jQuery);
```

I have two problems: 1) I can see that the HTML is being generated, but it does not appear to be added to the DOM. 2) I can't statically call the function. How can I make my function statically visible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few tweaks you need to make:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function(options) {
        var defaults = {
            theValue: 0
        },
            settings = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

        this.html($.myPlugin.getHtml(settings.theValue));
    };

    $.myPlugin = {
        getHtml: function(value) {
            return "<span>" + value + "</span>";
        }
    };

})(jQuery);
```

Usage:

```
$("#foo").myPlugin({ theValue: 10 });
var html = $.myPlugin.getHtml(10);
```

- First off, you were never calling the `init` method, so nothing was going to work. It isn't going to be called automatically. Perhaps you were thinking of the [jQueryUI widget factory](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138135/Widget%20factory)?
- Additionally, `element` doesn't get passed to the plugin, `this` refers the the element the plugin was called on. You only get passed `options`.
- Finally, to create a static jQuery method, just attach it right to `$`.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/xF2S6/